# Google +1 Button script not loading in local html file

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-plus-one

I'm playing around with the new Google +1 button and I've attempted to set up a simple demo of it.

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Plus One</title>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone callback="plus_one_callback" href="http://www.testurl.com/"></g:plusone>

<!--  Place this tag after the last plusone tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();

function plus_one_callback(){
    alert('callback');
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

However it does not render the button and there is no error message in my console.

Here is a screengrab of my firebug net panel:

[image: screenshot]

Anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work because as of Firefox 3 you can't run external JS scripts locally. Or to be more exact, you'll run into problems when firefox sees "file://" in the url. This question was also answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6732432/881250).  It probably would work if you used another browser.

If you really need this kind of stuff to work locally, however, there is a solution.  You can install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) to run a local server.